# Override of a controller

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I'm stuck at overriding a controller of a third party extension. I have followed the standard procedure for overriding a controller. I can't seem to get the route working.

I have done the following:

- Created my own Module
- Copied the path of the class I want to override
- Made a file in app/etc/modules - Module_Name.xml
- Made a config file in Module_Name/etc/ - config.xml
- Created the class and extended it with the class that I want to override

I think I've covered all the steps of overriding a controller.

Code part

In this part I will share all the file. I hope you guys can help me with this.

app/etc/modules/MDLOnline_PostNL.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MDLOnline_PostNL>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MDLOnline_PostNL>
    </modules>
</config>
```

MDLOnline/PostNL/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <MDLOnline_PostNL>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MDLOnline_PostNL>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <postnl>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MDLOnline_PostNL before="TIG_PostNL">MDLOnline_PostNL</MDLOnline_PostNL>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </postnl>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

Class override

MDLOnline/PostNL/controllers/PostnlAdminhtml/ShipmentController.php

```
<?php

require_once 'TIG/PostNL/controllers/PostnlAdminhtml/ShipmentController.php';

class MDLOnline_PostNL_PostnlAdminhtml_ShipmentController extends TIG_PostNL_PostnlAdminhtml_ShipmentController
{
    //override function
    public function massFullPostnlFlowAction($type = 'label')
    {
        die('custom controller');
    }

}
```

Class that needs to be override

TIG/PostNL/controllers/PostnlAdminhtml/ShipmentController.php

```
<?php

class TIG_PostNL_PostnlAdminhtml_ShipmentController extends TIG_PostNL_Controller_Adminhtml_Shipment
{
         //This function is overriden   
     public function massFullPostnlFlowAction($type = 'label')
     {
        /** @var TIG_PostNL_Helper_Carrier $helper */
        $helper = Mage::helper('postnl/carrier');

        $fullFlowAclResources = array(
            'create_shipment',
            'confirm',
            'print_label',
        );

        if (!$this->_checkIsAllowed($fullFlowAclResources)) {
            $helper->addSessionMessage(
                'adminhtml/session', 'POSTNL-0155', 'error',
                $this->__('The current user is not allowed to perform this action.')
            );

            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/index');

            return $this;
        }

        try {
            /**
             * Perform the full process for all selected orders.
             */
            $this->_fullPostnlFlow($type);
        } catch (TIG_PostNL_Model_Core_Cif_Exception $e) {
            /** @var TIG_PostNL_Helper_Cif $cifHelper */
            $cifHelper = Mage::helper('postnl/cif');
            $cifHelper->parseCifException($e);

            $helper->logException($e);
            $helper->addExceptionSessionMessage('adminhtml/session', $e);

            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/index');
            return $this;
        } catch (TIG_PostNL_Exception $e) {
            $helper->logException($e);
            $helper->addExceptionSessionMessage('adminhtml/session', $e);

            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/index');
            return $this;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $helper->logException($e);
            $helper->addSessionMessage('adminhtml/session', 'POSTNL-0010', 'error',
                $this->__('An error occurred while processing this action.')
            );

            $this->_redirect('adminhtml/sales_order/index');
            return $this;
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

TIG/PostNL/etc/config.xml
Admin Router

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <postnl_admin after="Mage_Adminhtml">TIG_PostNL</postnl_admin>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Comment: Could you share the admin router config part of the `TIG_PostNL` module ?

Comment: Can you add please the exact path's of your files and the config.xml of `TIG_PostNL`

Comment: Should I add the whole config.xml of TIG? It's a long document.

Comment: Try my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `app/etc/modules/MDLOnline_PostNL.xml` and not `app/etc/MDLOnline_PostNL.xml`
2. `MDLOnline/PostNL/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MDLOnline_PostNL>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MDLOnline_PostNL>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml> // not <postnl>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MDLOnline_PostNL before="TIG_PostNL">MDLOnline_PostNL</MDLOnline_PostNL>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

3. don't forget to clean the cache.

Comment: With pleasure, good luck !